# How do I set the customer priceLevel in NetSuite to blank/null?

Tags: c#, netsuite

I've been trying to set a customer object's priceLevel in NetSuite via c# to null/blank/empty value, but NetSuite seems to ignore it when I set the priceLevel to null, or to a new RecordRef with nothing further set.

[image]

When I manually set a priceLevel in the NetSuite web app to "blank" it appears as priceLevel = null when I read the customer object back in c#. But I am unable to manually set the priceLevel to null/empty/blank in code.

```
customer.priceLevel = new RecordRef();
```

or

```
customer.priceLevel = null;
```

Don't seem to work. NetSuite maintains the current non-null setting of priceLevel.

[image]

Comment: Try an empty string `customer.priceLevel = ""`, instead of null.

Comment: Since NetSuite is a commercial product, maybe you want to try contacting the  [Support Service](https://www.netsuite.com/portal/services/support-services.shtml)?

Comment: Happy to know that my answer might enlighten your question, you are welcome to check it as  answered.

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert in NetSuite, but I read the documentation, and here is my answer.

```
customer.priceLevel
```

`priceLevel` must be `PriceLevel` type. Therefore you need to do something like:

```
customer.priceLevel = new PriceLevel();
```

or with more details something without testing it or knowing which price you want to offer:

```
customer.priceLevel = new PriceLevel()
{
    name = String.Format(“{0:0.0}% Multiplier”, discountPercent), externalId = externalid, discountpct = discountPercent, discountpctSpecified = true
}
```

I gained my knowledge from this [article](https://followingnetsuite.com/2019/08/14/suitetalk-consistent-price-levels/).

---

**Edit**

Regarding your comment `Cannot implicitly convert type 'NSClient.com.netsuite.webservices.PriceLevel' to 'NSClient.com.netsuite.webservices.RecordRef'`, I think the example I provide might be valid for the previous version of NetSuite. That said, After further reading, the documentation, you need to create and set a record ref, and pass it to the price level. as mentioned, I do this without having profound knowledge about NetSuite. Her is an example.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();

RecordRef rt = new RecordRef();
rt.name = "PriceName";
rt.typeSpecified = true;
rt.internalId = "3";
rt.externalId = "4";
rt.type = RecordType.paymentMethod;

customer.priceLevel = rt;
```

documentation:

- https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/script/record/pricelevel.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3768988.html

Comment: I can't set customer.priceLevel to new PriceLevel() as they aren't the same type. I get this error 

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'NSClient.com.netsuite.webservices.PriceLevel' to 'NSClient.com.netsuite.webservices.RecordRef'`

Comment: @MatthewLock did you manage to solve it after my answer update?